# Making animated text in linux terminal

Tags: c++, linux, animation, terminal, libraries

I would like to make animated text inside of the Linux terminal.

By 'animated', I mean a single character constantly changing to make it form some sort of animation.
What I want is something like this:

```
|  # First second
/  # One second after previous frame
-  # One second after previous frame
|  # One second after previous frame
-  # One second after previous frame
\  # Last frame, skip back to top
```

...so it creates a line that appears to be spinning.

I am already quite aware of the method using `clear`, however this does not suit my needs.

`clear` removes all text, including previous text. I do not want this. I have seen plenty of animations in the terminal window not doing this (for example the loading bar shown using `apt install`), however, I have failed to reproduce.

How would I make an animation, such as a loading bar using the Linux terminal? If a library, I would prefer it being C++.

Comment: If it's in the first column of the current line, then you can use the carriage-return `'\r'` to go back, and overwrite the current character with the next. You can use the same method for a "loading bar", just go back to the start of the line, and overwrite what's already there.

Comment: use ncurses: https://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/intro.html

Comment: Please do not use standard output for this (it will look bad and cause other problems). Use `ncurses` library to have nice access to a console screen and bypassing standard output stream.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Doesn't seem to work. the `\r` appears to function like a `\n`.

Comment: Output streams are deliberately designed to be stupid because they have to behave the same on every platform, even those without anything you or I would consider a terminal. As soon as you need to so something smart, more than just stream bytes, consider using a library designed for that particular sort of smarts.

Comment: _If a library, I would prefer it being C++._ : C++ is not a library. It is a programming language.  As a general approach, I would first decide, at which place inside the terminal window the spinner has to be written to, then position the cursor to this place, and then print the character. If you don't want to use _ncurses_, but your terminal (which one are you using?) understands [ANSI escape codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code), you can use those. If you do it from a shell script, consider [tput](https://linux.die.net/man/1/tput).

Comment: @user1934428 By *if a library, I would prefer it being C++*, I meant that if it is a library, I would prefer that it is a library with C++ bindings.

Comment: It seems that for C++, this is  has been discussed [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/cpp_questions/comments/v66ofn/alternative_to_ncurses_for_modern_c_tui/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using tput is the key here which is part of ncurses.

This is the sample script which I wrote:-

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

clear  # Let clear the screen first

echo " Starting the spinning wheel.."
echo " Press 'q' or 'Q' to stop it.."

# to set the cursor position on terminal on row 2 column 1
tput cup 2 1

while true; do
   echo '|'
   sleep 1
   tput cup 2 1  # reset cursor position

   echo '/'
   sleep 1
   tput cup 2 1  # reset cursor position
   echo '-'

   sleep 1
   tput cup 2 1  # reset cursor position
   echo '\'

   sleep 1
   tput cup 2 1  # reset cursor position
   echo '|'

   tput cup 2 1  # reset cursor position
  # -t for timeout, -N to except only 1 character
   read -t 0.25 -N 1 ch
   if [[ $ch = "q" ]] || [[ $ch = "Q" ]]; then
       # The following line is for the prompt to appear on a new line.
        echo
        break
   fi

done
```

It's like a basic version. You can refine it further.
You can find the script here as well:- https://github.com/uv3003/uv/blob/main/rolling_pointer.sh

Regards,
Yuvraj